# How to change the Access Permission of Account Team Member

Tags: apex, administration, permissions, account-teams

I had added the team members via UI in Account Related List "Account Team". Is there a way to change the access permission of the Team Member.

Check the below image for reference. Using an existing Account Greendot Media, I have added a Team Member as Account Manager - while creating that Team Member I gave Read/Write Permission. Now when I edit that record to change permission, Img2 I get to edit only the Team Role and no other field is visible. But I wanted to change the access permission for that team member.

[image]

Comment: I am facing a lot of access permisisons issue in team members, recently in Opportunity & now in Accounts.
The only solution I got till now is to delete and recreate them, but I think that's not the only solution.

Comment: give a specific example for better clarification

Answer (score 1):

You can update the level of access of the Account Team members through the `Data Loader` as from UI you can not.

> Go to the Data Loader and Select Export  and make sure to click on Show all Salesforce Objects:

1. Export
2. Select Account Share (AccountShare)
3. Select all fields
4. Add the following condition: RowCause equals Team
5. Finish
6. Click on View Extraction
7. Click on Open in External Program

Depending on which related object(s) you want to update you can remove some of the fields or columns from the CSV file.

Update the file with the access that you prefer, the values in the Data Loader are different from Salesforce, for example:

None = Private

Read = Read Only

Edit = Read and Write

After you modify the file using the values None / Edit or Read, you need to go back into the Data Loader / select Update and Map the fields.

> After uploading the data, go to the Account Team related list and click on `Display Access` button to view the changes.

For more details on how it can be achieved, refer this link, [How to Mass Update Account Teams related objects access](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000148990)